# Set up a fresh deploy of a rails app with Capistrano. Deleted my deploy directory and re-deployed, now logs aren't working

Tags: capistrano, ruby-on-rails-6

Initially my log files were working, and during the process I blasted my deploy directory with a sudo rm -r. Now after I deploy with Capistrano, I'm not getting a log file in appname/logs/

How does rails know where its log file is? I expect I have broken symlink, or some such.

Comment: Well if you deploy with capistrano with a default setup, your log files will go to `appname/current/log`. Can you check if you have something there?

Comment: Yes. This is where the log file went initially. I wasn't happy with the deploy settings so I manually deleted it (in retrospect, I ought not to have done that, it seems...) After that, no log file. I created a file of the same name. It remains at 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! The missing piece of the equation was the site was initially deployed to Heroku and I moved it to a bare server. I don't know what voodoo and black magick Heroku does behind the scenes, but my best guess is they set up logging for you when you haven't done so yourself.  My app was missing code to create a logger in production. Adding one solved the issue.‍♂️